# JSON.stringify a react component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to `JSON.stringify` some react components for storage in a database. This works well for regular HTML, but not so great for react components. Take for example this div:

```
var content = (<div>some text</div>);
console.log(JSON.stringify(content));
```

I get this:

```
{
  "type": "div",
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "props": {
    "children": "some text"
  },
  "_owner": null,
  "_store": {}
}
```

Note that the JSON contains a `type` property referencing the `div`. However, note that when I do the same thing with a react component, the JSON doesn't contain a `type` property.

```
var content = (<TextWithPrompt />);
console.log(JSON.stringify(content));
```

Results in this:

```
{
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "props": {
    ...
  },
  "_owner": null,
  "_store": {}
}
```

I was expecting it to include a `"type": "TextWithPrompt"`. Any tips or suggestions to get that property included in the JSON output?

**TextWithPrompt.js**

```
export default class TextWithPrompt extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>This is text</div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: How come you're trying to store stringified components in a database? Can you store just the state and re-constitute the components on the front end?

Comment: Use react-test-rendrer